# Python - SQLite : Update two record with same identify value

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

i have a script like below :

```
import psutil

import sqlite3

DISK = {'1': ['C:\\', 'C:\\', 'NTFS', 'rw,fixed', '75.0Gb', '54.0Gb', '20.0Gb', '72.2%'], '2': ['D:\\', 'D:\\', 'NTFS', 'rw,fixed', '399.0Gb', '208.0Gb', '191.0Gb', '52.2%']}

conn = sqlite3.connect("Test.db")
c = conn.cursor()
result = c.execute("SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE IP = ?", ("192.168.10.111",))

if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
    for x in DISK :
        c.execute("UPDATE disk SET Device = ?, 'Mount Point' = ?, 'fstyle' = ?, 'opts' = ?, 'total' = ?, 'used' = ?, 'free' = ?, 'percent' = ? WHERE Client_IP = ?", (DISK[x][0], DISK[x][1], DISK[x][2], DISK[x][3], DISK[x][4], DISK[x][5], DISK[x][6], DISK[x][7], "192.168.10.111"))
else :
    for x in DISK :
    c.execute("INSERT INTO disk('Client_IP', 'Device', 'Mount Point', 'fstyle', 'opts', 'total', 'used', 'free', 'percent') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", ("192.168.10.111", DISK[x][0], DISK[x][1], DISK[x][2], DISK[x][3], DISK[x][4], DISK[x][5], DISK[x][6], DISK[x][7]))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Script will check in db if there is any record about IP "192.168.10.111". If db already have record about IP "192.168.10.111", Script will update data from dict **DISK** to table disk of db.
If db don't have record about IP "192.168.10.111", Script will create record to insert **DISK"" to database.

INSERT command work well but the UPDATE command don't work like i want. After INSERT command run, in table **disk** i will have two record about disk C and disk D with same value of column **Client_IP** (192.168.10.111).
After UPDATE, two record of IP "192.168.10.111" get same value on every column ehich is very wrong. One record must be contain information about disk C and another record cotain disk D information.

How can i make the UPDATE work right ? length of dict **DISK** depend on how many mounted devices the computer has. So i need to use for loop to UPDATE but not static UPDATE.

Please tell me how to fix this,
Many thanks,
Francis

Comment: Which columns identify the row you want to update?

Comment: it is Client_IP in table **disk**. please note that the SELECT is select from different table which is **clientinfo** not **disk**.

Comment: When you have multiple rows with the same Client_IP value, then this column does not identify the rows.

Comment: Yes, you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: When you get the two rows, how exactly do you determine which one is the correct one? Which column do you use to identify the one with the correct disk?

Answer (score 2):

Your `SELECT` query column value is incorrect based on your `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries later on. Instead of `IP`, should't it be `CLIENT_IP`? Also, you need to change your string query formatting. Remove the single quotes form your column names. Lastely, you can shorten your code by using a simple list comprehension and `cursor.executemany`:

```
import sqlite3
DISK = {'1': ['C:\\', 'C:\\', 'NTFS', 'rw,fixed', '75.0Gb', '54.0Gb', '20.0Gb', '72.2%'], '2': ['D:\\', 'D:\\', 'NTFS', 'rw,fixed', '399.0Gb', '208.0Gb', '191.0Gb', '52.2%']}

conn = sqlite3.connect("Test.db")
c = conn.cursor()
if not list(c.execute('SELECT * FROM lientinfo WHERE CLIENT_IP = ?',  ("192.168.10.111",))):
  c.executemany("INSERT INTO disk (Client_IP, Device, Mount Point, fstyle, opts, total, used, free, percent) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [["192.168.10.111", *i] for i in DISK.values()])
else:
   c.executemany('UPDATE disk SET Device = ?, Mount Point = ?, fstyle = ?, opts = ?, total = ?, used = ?, free = ?, percent = ? WHERE Client_IP = ?', [[*i, "192.168.10.111"] for i in DISK.values()])
```

Comment: Hi Ajax1234, the SELECT is right cause clientinfo is a different table which only have one column contain client IP. The INSERT and UPDATE is for table disk. But it doesn't matter, the problem is i can run your code. There is a Syntax error about ***i** . Please kindly note that i\m using Python 2.7.